# rsync doesn't sync changes

Tags: rsync

I didn't find exact what I  am looking for.

I made the first rsync to an USB stick:

```
rsync -uvarP --delete /var/lib/mysql /media/dag/BUCD03B
```

I made a minor change in my source and redo the sync. rsync finds a change, and sync, at least it shows me it syncs. But when I open the file, the change I made is not there. Can this be becasue of some buffering of data? Some of the data, also this source, are in a hidden directory. Also when I delete the source file in the destination folder, rsync does not transfer it anymore. I also tried with sudo rsync. That made me curious, so I deleted the directory containing the file in question. Now I see, that rsync neither transfered the deleted directory. 
What can be wrong?

Comment: From the label of the target filesystem I suppose it is a FAT formatted partition. I don't know if that works as it should, especially on hidden folders.

Comment: I looked, it is ext4. I always delete the partitions and create an ext4 on my USB. Of course it happens that I forget, this time not. But I will try with another.

Comment: I changed the USB and everything works. Thank for the idea to first look at the hardware ridgy :)